# Having trouble reproducing PHP heap based buffer overflow in quoted_printable_encode

Tags: php, buffer-overflow

I am trying to follow the test script provided [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64879). I've installed an apache web server with PHP version 5.3.25 and created a script with the following code:

```
<?php
// file: test.php
$str = quoted_printable_encode(str_repeat("\xf4", 1000));
echo "$str";
?>
```

I pointed my browser to "localhost/test.php" and I get a thousand '=F4's, but nothing indicates that PHP crashed or produced a segfault. I've increased the number to 1,000,000 but nothing changed, aside from the number of '=F4's. Has anyone else ever reproduced this or know of any resources with more info besides the page I've linked? I've been scouring Google for more information for weeks, but I only get bug report pages. Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you using? The bug reports do not indicate a lot of details, so it is hard to say what all the conditions are to trigger this crash.

Comment: I'm using Debian 3.2.65.

Comment: Apple and Ubuntu post bugs about this CVE, too. You could try on another OS to confirm.